# php sql adodb execute()

Tags: php, sql, adodb

```
$result = $myDB->Execute($query) or die(GetDbError($myDB->ErrorMsg()));
```

Lets say i wanna remove adodb form my script:

```
$result = $myDB->mysql_fetch_assoc($query) or die(GetDbError($myDB->ErrorMsg()));
```

It would be correct or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not correct - `mysql_fetch_assoc` is a function, not a method - and you would not even have a `$myDB` object.

I'd also suggest using PDO instead of the plain mysql/mysqli functions.

Answer (score 0):

If $myDB is an adodb object, then $result is an **ADORecordSet** object. You should fetch (or getAssoc()) on that $result. You're using adodb in order to avoid developing PHP code in a more abstract way, without using particular database engine functions. Then, if you need to move to another database system, you'll need to make minor changes to statements.

$array = $result->FetchRow();